# Laravel - How to Filter records using dopdown on submit

Tags: laravel

In my Laravel-5.8 project, I have this codes:

Model:

```
class HrEmployee extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'hr_employees';
    protected $primaryKey = 'id';

    protected $fillable = [
                  'id',
                  'department_id',
                  'first_name',
                  'last_name',
              ];

    public function department()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Hr\HrDepartment','department_id','id');
    }  
}
```

deptfilters in the controller filters the hr_employees table using department_id

Controller:

```
public function index(Request $request)
{
  $employeedatas = HrEmployee::where('status', 1)->get();
  $deptfilters = HrDepartment::where('status', 1)->pluck('department_name','id');

  return view('hr.employees.index')
    ->with('deptfilters', $deptfilters)
    ->with('employeedatas', $employeedatas);
}
```

view

```html
<div class="container">
  <br>
  <form action="ViewPages" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    @csrf
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <label for="from" class="col-form-label">Department</label>
        <div class="col-md-2">
          <select id="department" name="department" class="form-control">
            <option value="">--- Select department ---</option>
            @foreach ($department as $key => $value)
            <option value="{{ $key }}" {{ old( 'department')==$ key ? 'selected' : ''}}>{{ $value }}</option>
            @endforeach
          </select>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" name="search">Search</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
  <br>
  <table class="table table-dark">
    <tr>
      <th>id</th>
      <th>First Name</th>
      <th>Last Name</th>
      <th>Department</th>
    </tr>
    @foreach ($employeedatas as $employeedata)
    <tr>
      <td>{{ $employeedata->id }}</td>
      <td>{{ $employeedata->first_name }}</td>
      <td>{{ $employeedata->last_name }}</td>
      <td>{{ $employeedata->department->department_name }}</td>
    </tr>
    @endforeach
  </table>
</div>
```

From the code each department has many employees. What I want to achieve is that:

1. By default, the dropdown should load department where current_year = 1
2. When the search button is submitted, I want the table to be fields with records based on the department_id in the dropdown.

How do I modify my controller and view code to achieve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general you don't need for $table and $id property  when you are using Laravel conventions

```php
class HrEmployee extends Model
{
    //protected $table = 'hr_employees';//Laravel by default expect table name 'hr_employees'
    //protected $primaryKey = 'id';//Laravel by default expect primary_key on table is id column

    protected $fillable = [
                  'id',
                  'department_id',
                  'first_name',
                  'last_name',
              ];

    public function department()
    {
        //return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Hr\HrDepartment','department_id','id');
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Hr\HrDepartment');//No Need for override foreign key and owner key when you are using laravel conventions
    }  
}
```

In Controller

```php
public function index(Request $request)
{
  $employees = HrEmployee::where('status', 1);
  if($request->input('department_id')){
     $employees->where('department_id',$request->input('department_id'))
  }
  $employees=$employees->get();
  $departments = HrDepartment::where('current_year',1)->where('status', 1)->pluck('department_name','id');

  return view('hr.employees.index')
    ->with('departments', $departments)
    ->with('employees', $employees);
}
```

In View For filter use GET NOT POST METHOD

```html
<div class="container">
  <br>
  <form method="get">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <label for="from" class="col-form-label">Department</label>
        <div class="col-md-2">
          <select id="department" name="department_id" class="form-control">
            <option value="">--- Select department ---</option>
            @foreach ($departments as $id => $name)
            <option value="{{ $id }}" {{ request('depratment_id')==$id ? 'selected' : ''}}>{{ $name }}</option>
            @endforeach
          </select>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" name="search">Search</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
  <br>
  <table class="table table-dark">
    <tr>
      <th>id</th>
      <th>First Name</th>
      <th>Last Name</th>
      <th>Department</th>
    </tr>
    @foreach ($employees as $employee)
    <tr>
      <td>{{ $employee->id }}</td>
      <td>{{ $employee->first_name }}</td>
      <td>{{ $employee->last_name }}</td>
      <td>{{ optional($employee->department)->department_name }}</td>
    </tr>
    @endforeach
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks so much @anasomush it works. But if I want to add another button (Export to PDF) to export the filtered report to PDF. How do I alter my Controller and view to achieve that? Thanks

Comment: Welcome @user11352561 in your view add button with same route and current request params and add export_to_pdf with true and in your controller after employees actually retrieved check if  $request->input('export_to_pdf ') then pass $employees to exportPdf method and enjoy. hope this help you

Comment: @ananomush - I've done the view aspect, but remaining the controller. Is it possible to help update the controller

Answer (score 0):

You have pass the data using Ajax to the controller based on your filter values you should return the results of the filter without refreshing the page

Refer this
https://www.webslesson.info/2019/07/implement-custom-search-filter-in-laravel-58-datatable-using-ajax.html?m=1

Answer (score 0):

```php
public function index(Request $request)
{
    //Build initial query to fetch employee data
    $employeeQuery = HrEmployee::query()->where('status', 1);

    //If a department has been selected by user
    //filter the employee data by the selected department_id
    if(!empty($request->department)) {
        $employeeQuery->where('department_id', $request->department);          
    }

    //Get the employee data by executing the $employeeQuery
    $employeedatas = $employeeQuery->get();

    //Get all the departments where current_year = 1
    //if current_year is not a column on the departments table
    //replace where('current_year', 1) with whereYear('created_at',now()->format('Y'))
    //replace 'created_at' with whichever date column you want to compare with current year
    $deptfilters = HrDepartment::where('status', 1)
        ->where('current_year', 1)
        ->pluck('department_name','id');

  return view('hr.employees.index')
    ->with('deptfilters', $deptfilters)
    ->with('employeedatas', $employeedatas);
}
```